# OEM SSD not recognized by Samsung Magician

Tags: ssd, oem

My computer has a SM841 SSD (the OEM variant of the 840 Pro) *not* to be confused with the TLC **P**M841. Unfortunately, the Samsing Magician software doesn't recognize my drive, and will not let me enable any features (namely, RAPID). Is there any way to enable the features on this SSD?

Comment: forget the Rapid mode, it only slows down the SSD: http://superuser.com/a/742768/174557

Comment: Not every source agrees. I also own an 840 EVO, the speedups were very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a firmware update for the SSD.

Unfortunately, if the firmware is up to date and Magician still won't recognize the OEM variant, I think you're out of luck.  Samsung can be very picky about what SSDs they allow and don't allow with their software.