# Why is my SSD performing so far over spec?

Tags: ssd, storage, benchmarking

While setting up a new laptop, I plugged in an SSD from an old computer, a 1TB Samsung 840 EVO 2.5" SATA III. This drive is rated for 540 MB read / 520 write according to Samsung.

At first it only benchmarked at 316/501, but after fiddling with my power settings and installing Samsung Magician and doing some optimization, speeds jumped up to 1509/1764, faster than I thought SATA drives were known to go.

After transferring some data and wiping the drive, now it's benchmarking at 7079/8159! This is over twice as fast as my NVMe SSD (Western Digital SN720 1TB), which is running at 3223/2772. What is going on here? My NVMe slots are PCIe3 so I suspect I can't get it much faster than it already is, but why is my SATA drive blowing it away?

Numbers given are from CrystalDiskMark Sequential Q8T1.

Comment: You might be testing your memory buffers instead of the disk.

Comment: See this question about rapid mode. https://superuser.com/questions/742765/is-it-beneficial-to-enable-rapid-mode-on-a-samsung-solid-state-drive

Comment: @kicken Thanks for that. It would appear that RAPID creates a memory buffer that allows for ridiculously high benchmarks, but actually slows down real-world performance? I have a disgusting amount of RAM and the disk is only used for data, does that advice still apply?

Comment: @VinnyDiehl, with a decent amount of memory backing it I doubt it'd actively harm your day-to-day experience, but it certainly wouldn't provide as much help as the benchmarks might make it seem.  Most likely you'd see no real difference and just experience normal SATA III speeds.